# Check that files exist on remote server with different directory structure or organization

Tags: linux, bash, nas, data-transfer, data-integrity

I have made a NAS project to replace an aging shared external disk drive, and before decomissioning the old shared disk drive, I'd like to verify that I have copied all important data to the new NAS. Normally this wouldn't be an issue, but I've been using the NAS since creating the new share and initially copying data.

This use includes adding new files which weren't on the original shared external HDD, reorganizing the structure of data to be more clean and properly labeled or stored (new directories, possibly different filenames and permissions) and pruning unneeded data from the original copy.

Is there an easy way to verify that files from the original share exist on the new share (even with different directories, names, or permissions) and generate a list of files which aren't, while ignoring files which are new on the new share?

I'm thinking that this isn't going to be a single-command job, and I'll have to write some sort of script to recursively compare checksums of files.. I wanted to throw it to the community before setting about this first, as I'm likely not the first to encounter this or something similar.

Also note that, while both systems are not running the same OS, both are capable of running BASH scripts with most standard commands shared between them, or even python if that fits your fancy. (OS X 11.10 w/macports & homebrew vs Armbian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. Following trying to write a script which worked with varied success (Weird filenames tripped it up, and it was very difficult to work with sanitizing them in BASH), I ended up finding a program called [Checksum Compare](http://checksumcompare.sanktuaire.com/home) which does exactly what I was seeking to do.